# CPU & Memory spikes, during Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#

I am building an application for work to copy files and folders, with a few more options but these are not being utilised during this issue.

The function in question iterates through each file in a directory, and then copies the file to an identical directory, in a new location (so it preserves nested file structures).

The application is a Windows Form, and due to issues writing to a text box at the same time, I have surrounded the parallel function in a Task.Factory.StartNew(), which fixed that issue.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Parallel.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(root, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories), newPath =>
    {
        try
        {
            File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(root, destination), false);
            WriteToOutput("recreated the file '" + newPath.Replace(root, destination) + "'");                                
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
             WriteToOutput(e.Message);
         }
     });
});
```

When run, the diagnostic tools show spikes every few seconds. How can I 'even out' these spikes and make the performance consistent? I am also writing to the screen for each file that is moved, and there is a noticeable second or so pause between every maybe, 20/25 files.

The below screenshot is a sample from the Diagnostic Tools.

[image]

Comment: One good way to experiment with threading effects for copying is to use `robocopy /MT:n` feature to copy a representative set of data across some typical source and target drive configurations.  I think you will find that `n > 2` is faster than `n == 1`, but there will be a point of decreasing returns.  My experience has been `/MT:4` has been a good choice in the past, but for lots of small files, `/MT:8` can be measurably better. That will give you some clues you can apply to selecting how many threads your application should use and when. Maybe you'll want to make it configurable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your work is primarily IO bound, not CPU bound.  You don't *have* any work for a CPU to do most of the time.  You're just waiting for the hard drive to do *its* work.  The spikes in your CPU are merely the short periods of time after the disk has finished an operation where the CPU is trying to figure out what to ask it to do next, which takes very little time, hence why you see spikes, not plateaus.

Comment: Ah okay, so these spikes are not something to be concerned about?

Answer (score 3):

I am concerned by this sentence:

> due to issues writing to a text box at the same time, I have surrounded the parallel function in a Task.Factory.StartNew(), which fixed that issue

I honestly doubt that fixed the issue. It probably concealed it. You do not appear to be awaiting or checking on the Task, so you are therefore not observing any exceptions. The short CPU spike and the delay in output could easily be caused by a stack unwind of some kind.

If you having trouble updating the UI from your worker threads, make sure you understand the purpose of [Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) and be sure you are using it. Then get rid of the `StartNew`, or make sure you are handling any exceptions.

Comment: Okay, I'll look further into my usage here. To be honest it did seem a bit _too_ easy of a fix to the problem. Thank you for the reference also.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is to press the disk with many file read requests in parallel. Well, disks, like any other I/O device, don't work well in that mode.

For one thing, if you're reading the HDD, then it definitely cannot answer the parallel requests simply because it would have to move the reading head to multiple locations at the same time.

Even with an SDD, the device cannot answer the requests at the same rate at which CPU can ask.

In any case, the disk will definitely not be able to return the data at uniform speed. Many file read requests will be pending for the whole eternity (measured in CPU time), leaving those tasks blocked. That is the reason why performance is uneven when storming the disk with many parallel operations.

When attempting to process many files, you might choose to allocate one task to read them, and then process the loaded data in parallel. Think about that design instead. The I/O-bound task would be only one and it won't be blocked more than necessary. That will let the drive return the data at maximum speed which it can achieve at the time. The CPU-bound tasks would be non-blocking, obviously, because their data would already be in memory at the time any of the tasks is started. I would expect that design to provide smooth performance.

Comment: Okay thank you for your answer. I am reading from an SSD and writing to a HDD, and I didn't even consider the physical limitation on a HDD. So since I'm not processing, in the sense of not opening the file, and all tasks are IO intensive, would you say using a parallel loop is unnecessary?

Comment: In that case, yes, I think that parallel loop is doing damage when you take all effects into consideration. You should measure effects, but my guess is that one task to read and one task to write is all you need. On a related note, two tasks will perform better than one, because there is still *some* CPU work to be done.

Comment: NTFS maintains a queue of I/O operations to be performed on the disk and will reorder operations to optimize total through-put. When file sizes are fairly random and mostly small, it does not hurt to have multiple readers/writers and can often speed things up a bit. Just look at the performance differences between `robocopy /mt:1` and `robocopy /mt:4`.